# How do I get a count of matching literals when matching regex's in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

For context, my use-case is the determine a "precision" score of a regex as it relates to an input string, for the purposes of ranking. While I realize that regex precision can be a nebulous concept, I am defining it for my use-case as the number of matching literals.

Here is an example of inputs & expected results from this mythical function:

```
>>> get_literal_count(regex=r'foo(bizz|b[a-z]+)*', string='foobarbar')
>>> 5
```

The way that example breaks down to get a result of 5:

```
foo [3 literals]
(bizz| [Not matching = 0 literals]
b[a-z]+)* [1 literal (the "b") matched 2 times = 2 literals]
```

My investigation and playing around with re & sre_parse modules have lead me to the conclusion that the only way to achieve what I am after is to essentially re-write a home-brew re.match function using sre_parse that tracks the number of matching literals as it goes.

Going down that path, I would need to re-implement all (or at least a large sub-set) of the sre symbols used in matching, just to end up with what is essentially a really slow re.match function (the standard lib re.match is written in C, but my implementation would be in Python), I pose my question here.

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? Is there a better way?

EDIT: To clarify, the regex being used in my example is arbitrary, the method must operate on any regex.